# uC/OS II memory management,OSMemPut() return the memory block without memory clear

Tags: memory, ucos

I am a newbie about uC/os II, and confused with the memory management.
     In function OSMemGet(), we can see that task require the first block of the memory area's linked list(OSMemFreeList),
     then in OSMemPut(), return the used block to OSMemFreeList's first block without memory clean.
     If there is a task get a block ,store an int (eg. 250) into it, then return this block . Later in this task OSMemGet() require this block again, is int 250 still in this block? How can I read it again?

Answer (score 0):

aha , I know how to get previous stored content now. every memory block we get from the OSMemFreeList, storing next block's address in it's first 4 bytes,we need skip these bytes ,then we can read these data again for ucos does not clear memory block in OSMemPut().

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to access blocks you have put back, so there's no guarantee this will work in the future. What you are seeing in those first 4 bytes is the address of the next block. The free blocks are stored as a linked list so as they are created / put back, they are relinked in the chain.